# How to create application icon with icon on desktop in KDE?

Tags: 18.04, kde

I have used `Create new` -> `Link to Application` and copied content of application launcher entry of `CLion` to there, but appeared icon got no icon.

Why and how to fix?

[image: kde]

Comment: What is the output of `cat "Link to Application.desktop"`?

Comment: You should specify an icon somewhere in that dialog. Otherwise, the system falls back to a default icon (or eventually none apparently in your case).